# Integrate third party chatbot with Grafana

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I have been trying out botpress for creating a chatbot to use on my react website and grafana. I was able to successfully display it on my react website by following the instructions provided in the following link: https://botpress.com/docs/developers/webchat/embedding-webchat-options/react-app/

But I am unable to find any documentations to do the same thing in Grafana. Can someone help with the steps or procedure to have the botpress chatbot on my grafana app too. I am using the Open Source version of Grafana(9.4.13)